# Retrieve Google Sheet with googlesheets4 when authorization is to a non-google email account

Tags: r, googlesheets4

A client has shared a bunch of google sheets with me using my non-google email.  When I click on the link to the sheet, google sends me a 6-digit code via that email which I type in when google prompts me prior to opening the sheet.

I want to automate downloading these sheets on a regular basis. I tried googlesheets4 gs4_auth(email="myemail@somewhere.com"), but that fails because it wants me to authorize with a gmail account.  If I just try read_sheet(), without authorization I get 'permission denied'.

Is there a way to authorize with the 6-digit code that google sends me?